# Timer not cancelling flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I needed a single instance of a timer to run on my app such that i can cancel and reinitialise it when needed. However, the timer doesn't cancel after calling the `.cancel()` operation. It only work if i call it from the default constructor but i want a global timer i can cancel anytime;

```
Timer timer;

  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) async {
         //cancelling timer only works here e.g (t.cancel)
  print("loop operation");
        });

timer.cancel(); // calling this method outside the constructor don't work.
```

Comment: By far the most common mistake I've seen when people claim that `Timer` cancellation doesn't work is that they accidentally create multiple `Timer` objects and clobber the previous reference.  Please post a reproducible example and verify that you are not leaking `Timer`s.

Comment: @jamesdlin that was my case bro. fixed now. thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. This happened after I made the callback function `async`.

I think the solution will differ from problem to problem depending on why your callback is `async`.

*This is not a solution, but rather a hint to get you closer to the solution.*

Comment: Interestingly I had the same issue, once removed `async` from the callback definition it cancelled the timer correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer timer;

Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) async {
            timer = t;
            print("loop operation");
        });


//inside a button callback
timer??.cancel(); // perform null check as well before cancelling.
```